Method overloaded only on const-qualifier
In most cases if we overload a member function on constness, the two overloads have different return type or parameter types. In most cases the return type is different. The function usually returns a member variable, and the return type is a reference which differs in constness:
struct IntArray {
    int&       Get(size_t i);           // mutable returns mutable reference
    const int& Get(size_t i) const;     // const returns const reference
};

But, is there a use case where it makes sense to have two member functions with identical return and parameter types, which differ only in const-qualification? E.g.:
struct SomeType {
    Ret Method(Par1, Par2, Par3);
    Ret Method(Par1, Par2, Par3) const;
};


In that case we could write only const version.  Complier is allow access const member/method  from mutable object.

Here are some references. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view/base, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view/size

Do you have a specific problem in mind? Because I fail to see how this question has any practical implications.

Can't think of one. Whatever Method() is doing, it either changes SomeTypes state or it does not (that's the const case).  Wouldn't make sense to have both.

If the two Method members were to do different things, they should also have different names. If they do the same thing, we only need one of them.

Maybe some operations implement some kind of caching to be fast on next execution. But sometimes it is not wanted to change the cached data, you can go with a const object which can't modify the cache.

We might have both when "logical" const mismatch with language const, i.e caching/synchronization.
The general approach in that case would be mutable fields though (and possibly making it thread safe).
But if we want the guarantee of non-mutability, it might make sense to have both:
class SomeType {
public:
    Ret Method(Par p) const {
        if (auto it = cache.find(p); it != cache.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else { // no mutating, and no cache update
            return Compute(p);
        }
    }
    Ret Method(Par p) {
        if (auto it = cache.find(p); it != cache.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else { // mutating
            return cache.emplace(p, Compute(p)).first->second;
        }
    }

private:
    static Ret Compute(Par p);
private:
    std::map<Par, Ret> cache;
};


This idea, although intriguing, seems to be purely theoretical.

I never saw that in practice. I encounter mutable cache, possibly with mutable std::mutex though.
